# Multiple access to sqlite database using sqlite swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, sqlite.swift

Here's my scenario,

I have multiple request when I log in to my app, and in one of it's response contains 10,000 + records.

I am using SQLite.swift in my project.

All is working fine if the user doesn't logout or doesn't more than 1 task like searching or retrieving data from db. if any of the case happens then the app gets stuck or crashes.

I am using transactions for bulk insert, but when I try to access another same table data then the app freezes until everything is done.

I tried using multiple connections to insert to db but if another connection is using the db then its locked and app crashes

> fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: database
>   is locked: file
>   /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-703.0.18.1/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift,
>   line 54

```
try DataManager.con.transaction {

            for index in 0 ... (entity.count - 1) {
            try DataManager.con.run(table.insert(
                    Latitude <- entity[index]["Latitude"].string,
                    Longitude <- entity[index]["Longitude"].string
                ))
            }
        }
```

Here DataManager.con is a singleton object

Please help.

Comment: Perform your db transactions on the background thread or any other threads other than `main thread`.

Comment: @Santosh I am doing the same, the bulk insert are in background thread, as I am using a singleton db object when I try to access another table it freezes

Comment: There can be multiple reason and you have not provided relevant information , i.e CoreData.SQLDebug logs, susceptible code block, etc.

Comment: @K.Nimo I am not using CoreData, simply using Stephen Celis sqlite.swift

Comment: If you put relevant code/crash logs, then it would be helpful for debugging.

Comment: @Santosh I have added the crash log. I will add the code snippets I am using now. Hope this helps

Comment: "Database is locked" is a concurrency error that SQLite.swift is supposed to prevent: you should open an issue in their Github repository. Meanwhile, have a thorough read of https://medium.com/@gwendal.roue/four-different-ways-to-handle-sqlite-concurrency-db3bcc74d00e

Comment: @GwendalRoué I solved it by moving couple of tables to different db, like the master data tables. for accessing that I used another db connection, which wont block my main thread

Comment: Great @vinbhai4u! I still think you should warn the library author(s) of your issue, so that they know about it.

Comment: Bulk request you can process using FMDB https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb Some configured example is here https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/SQLite_SingleManagerClass

Comment: Sqlite.swift claims to be thread-safe so why is this happening?

Comment: @Gwendal Roué Thank you for the link. I was using different queues for downloading in my app and was getting the same error. so, I created a serial queue for all inserts with transactions and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With sqlite.swift it was not possible to create concurrent connections.

So I moved my master data to another db and create a separate connection for it.

I also added

```
do{
// Start transaction
// code
// Commit transaction
}
catch {
}
```

to handle errors if user logout or closes the app, Transaction will help to maintain partial data saving also

Thanks to all who helped.